# How to write a test list of the Trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I am very new at the development. I finish writing the Trigger but have no idea with the test code. I trying to write the test code but get 0% of code coverage. 
Here is my Trigger and test code. Hoping someone can help me. Thank you!

**Trigger**

```
   trigger UpdateQuoteStatus on QuoteLineItem (after insert, after update)
{
    List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();

    for(QuoteLineItem q : Trigger.New)
    {
        if(q.UnitPrice != q.Apex_price__c)
        {
           quoteList.add(new Quote(Id = q.QuoteId, Status = 'Needs Review', Sales_Price_not_List_Price__c = 'Yes', RecordTypeId = '0126F000001KDtwQAG'));
        }
       if(q.Discount != 0 && q.Discount != null)
        {
          quoteList.add(new Quote(Id = q.QuoteId, Status = 'Needs Review', Discount_not_0__c = 'Yes', RecordTypeId = '0126F000001KDtwQAG'));
        }
    }
    map<Id,Quote> accmap = new map<Id,Quote>();
    accmap.putall(quoteList );
    if(accmap.size()>0){
    update accmap.values();
    }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
@isTest
private class TestUpdateQuoteStatus {
    @isTest static void TestUpdateQuoteStatusWithPrice() {
        QuoteLineItem  acct = new QuoteLineItem (UnitPrice =8.11,Discount=0);
        PricebookEntry PbE = new PricebookEntry(UnitPrice =8.11);
       Test.startTest();
       try{
            insert acct;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Test.stopTest();
        }    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the try/catch from your test and fix any errors generated by the insert. Then add asserts to confirm the behavior. Then add further test methods to check the various data permutations.

You will then have 100% code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Apex testing unit.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing

It is a very simple problem which you mentioned. Once you complete this unit you will easily be able to solve this by your own.